# External website content + possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Tags: javascript, node.js

I using node js and I have 100 or more URL's in array list.
I am trying  to get all url's metadata. so i used "request" and "cheerio" packages.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var resultData = ["http://www.realsimple.com/food-recipes/9-healthy-predinner-snacks", "http://www.womenshealthmag.com/weight-loss/100-calorie-snacks", "https://www.pinterest.com/explore/healthy-snacks/", "http://www.rd.com/slideshows/healthy-snacks-for-adults/", "http://greatist.com/snacking", "http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/26-best-healthy-snacks.html"];

var keyObject = new Array();

for (var index in resultData) {
    var resourceUrl = resultData[index];
    request(resourceUrl, function(error, response, html) {
       if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {         
       var $ = cheerio.load(html);
       $('meta').each(function(i, element) {
            if ((element.attribs.name == 'Keywords') || (element.attribs.name == 'keywords')) {             
               var keyObject = new Object();
               keyObject.url = response.request.uri.href;
               keyObject.key = element.attribs.content;
               resourceDetails.push(keyObject);
            }
       });
      }
   });
}
```

Once i run the code i get maximum 5 to 10 results. then i getting error:

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace at Request.EventEmitter.addListener (events.js:160:15)
```

Then i search in google need to add in loop self.setMaxListeners(0);

```
var keyObject = new Array();

for (var index in resultData) {
    var resourceUrl = resultData[index];
    request(resourceUrl, function(error, response, html) {
       if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
       self.setMaxListeners(0);
       var $ = cheerio.load(html);
       $('meta').each(function(i, element) {
            if ((element.attribs.name == 'Keywords') || (element.attribs.name == 'keywords')) {             
               var keyObject = new Object();
               keyObject.url = response.request.uri.href;
               keyObject.key = element.attribs.content;
               resourceDetails.push(keyObject);
            }
       });
      }
   });
}
```

But i didn't get any output. I don't know now going correct way.

Excepted output :

```
[{"url" : "http:example.com", "key" : "metadata list"},{"url" : "http:example.com", "key" : "metadata list"},{"url" : "http:example.com", "key" : "metadata list"},{"url" : "http:example.com", "key" : "metadata list"},{"url" : "http:example.com", "key" : "metadata list"},{"url" : "http:example.com", "key" : "metadata list"}]  etc
```

Comment: You probably want a recursive function that requests the next url when the current is finished etc. not do 100 request at the same time ?

Comment: Recursive function ?  can you have any sample for that.  I am new for this.

Comment: Untested and in a hurry, something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/wv8pr89b/